# Inequality with Logarithms!

Tags: inequality, logarithms, classical-mechanics

I need some help solving this inequality for a question involving the number of bounces, $n$, of ball such that the max. height of the ball is less than 5cm. This is the equation I have gathered from the previous information of the question.

$\frac{(\alpha^n\beta)^2}{2g}$ $<0.05$

I need $n>constant$ but I'm having difficulty with inequality signs with the logarithm.

Here $g=9.8ms^{-2}$, $\alpha<1$ and $\beta>1$.

Comment: Is it possible to write the above fraction using only variables? It's hard to tell what is multiplication and what is a decimal point in your formatting.

Comment: I have edited the question, hopefully that is clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a,b,c,d>0$ and $n\in\Bbb N$. Then we have

$$ \frac{(a^nb)^2}{c}<d \iff (a^nb)^2<dc \iff a^nb<\sqrt{dc} \iff a^n < \frac{\sqrt{dc}}{b} \\ \iff n\ln(a)=\ln(a^n)<\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{dc}}{b}\right) \qquad (*)$$

Where the fact that $x\mapsto \ln(x)$ is strictly increasing is used in the last equivalence.

Now if $a >1$, then $\ln(a)>0$ and $(*)$ is true if and only if $$n < \frac{\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{dc}}{b}\right) }{\ln(a)}$$
and this shows that the constant you are looking for does not exists, i.e. there is no $C>0$ such that the inequality is satisfied for every $n>C$.

If $a=1$ then $\ln(a)=0$ and $(*)$ is true for every $n$ as long as $\frac{\sqrt{dc}}{b}>1$.

Finally if $a<1$, then $\ln(a)<0$ and $(*)$ is true if and only if 
$$n > \frac{\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{dc}}{b}\right) }{\ln(a)}.$$

Comment: I think in his example $a<1$ (before the first edit, it was $2/3$ if I remember well) so that $ln(a)<0$...

Comment: @ClémentGuérin thank you, I edited to treat every case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. At what point do I change the inequality sign?

Comment: @George not that for every $p,q,r\in\Bbb R$ if $r<0$, then we have $pr < q \iff p>\frac{q}{r}$ this comes from the fact that $p<q \iff -p>-q$.

Comment: @George Whenever you apply a function that changes the sign of the slope.  In this case, when $a<1$ you have $\log a<0$, so dividing both sides by it changes the direction of the inequality.

Comment: @George is there any problem in my answer?